# Proving a set is open and coming up with an example

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, elementary-set-theory, metric-spaces

i) Let $a \in A$ and $\epsilon>0$. Prove that $U(x0,\epsilon):={a∈A:d(x0,a)<\epsilon}$ is open.

ii) Let $B \subset A$. Show a set X that is open in B but not open in A. Then show a set Y that is closed in B but not closed in A.

iii) Let $X \subset A$. Prove if Z is closed and contained in A and Z contains X,then Z contains $\overline X$.

For i) i assume it is just the definition of an open ball so it has to be open. for ii), i am not too sure how i would come up with the two sets, any hints or help would be appreciated.

for iii), i assume the X is not related to the X in part ii), but to show C contains the boundary of X, isn't it trivial since C is closed and contains A so it has to contain the boundary?

Comment: in i). I think you have to prove than the open ball is an open set. though it seems obvious,you still have to prove it. so given an arbitrary element $t$ in the open ball $B(x_0; \epsilon)$, you have to find a distance $\delta$ such that $B(t; \delta) $ is contained in the open ball $B(x_0; \epsilon)$.

Comment: got it thanks and for iii) is the X related to the X in part ii) or it is not?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Consider $(0,1]\subset\Bbb R$, for starters.  Now look at $(1/2,1]\subset(0,1]$. The set $(1/2,1]$ is open in $(0,1]$, but not in $\Bbb R$.  Next try $(0,1/2]$, say, to get the rest of ii).

For iii) recall that the closure, $\bar A$,  is the smallest closed set containing $A$.

Comment: can you explain iii) a little more? i got the definition wrong but since C is closed and contains A, isnt it still obvious that A closure is contained in C? thanks

Comment: It is.  Because either $C$ is the smallest closed set containing $A$, in which case $C=\bar A$, or else $\bar A\subsetneq C$.

Comment: so is there a way I need to prove iii) in a particular way? since it seems trivial to just write that down

Comment: Well, I guess just pay lip service, and cite the equivalent definition.

Comment: for ii) why is the set (1/2,1]  open in (0,1] sorry i might be a little confused on the definition

Comment: Use a).  Each $x\in(1/2,1]$ has $x\in U(x,\epsilon)\subset (1/2,1]$, for certain $\epsilon$, with $U(x,\epsilon)$ open by a).